# Find the Fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ and $X=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4:-1\le x_i\le1, i=1,2,3,4\}$.

If $Z\subset X$ is the boundary of $X$ minus the intersection with the coordinating axes, and if $p\in Z$ how can i calculate $\pi_1(Z,p)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry I mean the boundary

Comment: So basically this space is the sphere $S^3$ with eight points removed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so it is a concatenation of 8 circumferences and then $\pi_1 (Z,p)=\mathbb{Z}*...*\mathbb{Z}$ eight times?

Comment: @Richy65 If you consider the stereographic projection, $Z$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb R^3$ with 7 points removed, and that's a simply connected space. In fact, it's homotopy equivalent to a wedge of seven 2-spheres.

Comment: @Kevin.S do you want to post that as an answer?